# Storing a picture returns a solid block of color instead of a picture

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to understand why this code stores a solid black image instead of the picture I'm trying to upload (i.e. the image is never stored, just a black box with the same measurements as the picture I'm uploading)?

```
    Protected Sub btn_FileUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_FileUpload.Click
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim FileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName.ToLower())
            Dim allowedExtensions As String() = {".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".gif"}

            If Not FileUpload1.FileContent.Length > "1024000" Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To allowedExtensions.Length - 1
                    If FileExtension = allowedExtensions(i) Then
                        Try
                            SaveImageFile(FileUpload1, Server.MapPath("~/Profile/ImageBank/Temp/image-" & GetStubs.GetUserGuid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()) & ".jpg"), "600")
                            Response.Redirect(Utilities.Helpers.ResolveUrl("~/MyProfile.aspx?tab=crop"))
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            lblError.Text = "Bilden kunde inte laddas upp." + ex.Message.ToString()
                        End Try

                    End If
                Next
            Else
                lblError.Text = "Filen du försöker att ladda upp är större en 1 Mb. Välj en annan bild eller spara bilden i ett annat filformat."
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SaveImageFile(ByVal clientFile As FileUpload, ByVal saveImagePath As String, ByVal maxImageWidth As Integer)
        Dim sourceImage As New Bitmap(clientFile.PostedFile.InputStream)

        ' Resize if source image width is greater than the max:
        If sourceImage.Width > maxImageWidth Then
            Dim newImageHeight As Integer = CInt(sourceImage.Height * (CSng(maxImageWidth) / CSng(sourceImage.Width)))
            Dim resizedImage As New Bitmap(maxImageWidth, newImageHeight)

            ' Save the resized image:
            resizedImage.Save(saveImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            resizedImage.Dispose()
        Else
            ' Save the source image (no resizing necessary):
            sourceImage.Save(saveImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            sourceImage.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

And this is the form...

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />                        
    <span class="button-field">
        <asp:Button ID="btn_FileUpload" runat="server" Text="Ladda upp" OnClick="btn_FileUpload_Click" />
    </span>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" CssClass="red" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: I don't see any code where you resize `sourceImage` into `resizedImage` - did you omit that part in your question?

Comment: In the `SaveImageFile` method when the image is resized, you are setting the size of the new bitmap, but you are not filling it with the original content, so your result is a black colored rectangle with the specified size. IMO you are missing something like this contructor: [Bitmap(originalImage, newSize)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: So these lines aren't doing that?             `Dim newImageHeight As Integer = CInt(sourceImage.Height * (CSng(maxImageWidth) / CSng(sourceImage.Width)))
            Dim resizedImage As New Bitmap(maxImageWidth, newImageHeight)
            resizedImage.Save(saveImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)`. I'm trying to grasp how I should implement it - must I declare a new BitMap-variable and then add save to that?

Comment: I omitted these lines as they threw errors. I don't really understand why they do throw errors...
            `Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage)

            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            gr.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, maxImageWidth, newImageHeight)`

Comment: I've tried to add the sourceImage to the existing New Bitmap as follows with no luck: `Dim resizedImage As New Bitmap(sourceImage, maxImageWidth, newImageHeight)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the SaveImageFile method into this:

```
    Public Shared Sub SaveImageFile(ByVal clientFile As FileUpload, ByVal saveImagePath As String, ByVal maxImageWidth As Integer)
        Dim sourceImage As New Bitmap(clientFile.PostedFile.InputStream)

        ' Resize if source image width is greater than the max:
        If sourceImage.Width > maxImageWidth Then
            Dim newImageHeight As Integer = CInt(sourceImage.Height * (CSng(maxImageWidth) / CSng(sourceImage.Width)))
            Dim resizedImage As New Bitmap(sourceImage, maxImageWidth, newImageHeight)
            Dim canvas As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage)

            ' Save the resized image:
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            canvas.DrawImage(resizedImage, New Point(0, 0))
            resizedImage.Save(saveImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            resizedImage.Dispose()
        Else
            ' Save the source image (no resizing necessary):
            sourceImage.Save(saveImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            sourceImage.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you @Andrew Morton and @pasty for pointing this out to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you are uploading either a gif or a png.  gif and png support transparency, but jpeg does not.  The transparency/alpha channel from the gif/png file stores as black when saving as a jpeg.

To retain transparency/alpha channel and clarity, save the images as their original file types.

Comment: It's a valid point, but actually I'm trying to upload a .jpg and save it as a .jpg. :/